# How do I require an input to my InputBox before executing the macro?

Tags: vba, excel

My macro requires an input as soon as the macro is executed. However, if a user presses cancel, the macro will execute without this information, which leaves holes in the data. Here was my best guess, but it doesn't prevent users from cancelling and still executes:

```
        Do Until Not IsEmpty(myWknum)
        DoEvents

            myWknum = InputBox("Please enter week number")

        Loop
```

Comment: What means "didn't work"? Please edit the question and add more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, when the user cancels the `InputBox`, you wish to exit the subroutine without processing anything further, use the `Exit Sub` statement:

```
Sub Test
    Dim myWkNum As String
    myWkNum = InputBox("Please enter week number")
    If myWkNum = "" Then Exit Sub
    '...
    'other code
    '...
End Sub
```

or, with some validity testing:

```
Sub Test
    Dim myWkNum As String
    Do
        myWkNum = InputBox("Please enter week number")
        If myWkNum = "" Then
            Exit Sub
        ElseIf IsNumeric(myWkNum) Then
            If myWkNum > 0 And myWkNum < 54 And Int(myWkNum) = myWkNum Then
                Exit Do
            End If
        End If
    Loop
    '...
    'other code
    '...
End Sub
```

Comment: Nice checking for `Int()` too :D

Comment: @BruceWayne I had to one-up your tests! :D  (And I live in the real world, where there is sometimes a need for a week 53 too ;) )

Answer (score 2):

This will force a value, and that value must be a number:

```
Sub t()
Dim myWknum As String

Do While myWknum = "" Or Not IsNumeric(myWknum)
    myWknum = InputBox("Please enter week number")
Loop
End Sub
```

And this, a little more verbose (and can probably be made more efficient), will force the user to input a number from 1 to 52:

```
Sub t()
Dim myWknum As String

Do While myWknum = "" Or Not IsNumeric(myWknum)
    myWknum = InputBox("Please enter week number")
Loop

If myWknum < 1 Or myWknum > 52 Then
    Do While myWknum < 1 Or myWknum > 52
        myWknum = InputBox("Please use a valid week number. (>= 1 or <= 52)")
    Loop
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: If week number is not valid you should begin from the first loop. Otherwise there is no `IsNumeric(myWknum)` for the second `InputBox`.

Comment: @omegastripes - What do you mean? Only when you pass a number through does it go to the second loop. If you input like `Three` or `3dsju` the first loop keeps asking for a week number until you give it strictly a number. Then it checks that number and sees if it's from 1 to 52.

Comment: @BruceWayne Thank you! Worked perfectly.

Comment: (@Christopher - If so, you can flag it as the answer, by clicking the check mark left of the post, under the up/down arrows)

Comment: @BruceWayne If the user enters `5261` on the first `InputBox`, then enters `xyz` on the second `InputBox`, it will crash.  You need to check `IsNumeric(myWkNum)` again before testing against numeric values.  (So you should probably just use one loop.)

Comment: @YowE3K - Ahhh, yes I see what y'all mean now.

Comment: @Christopher - For what it's worth, YowE3K's answer is worth looking in to for the reasons he and omegastripes mention. If someone types something other than a number in the second loop, it'll error.  (Feel free to switch the answer too, if you see fit.)

Answer (score 0):

add this before the `Loop` line.

`if myWknum="" then Exit Do`

Comment: Quite the opposite

Comment: Oh you are trying to prevent them from using Cancel? That will be horribly annoying to the user.